# jQuery append html element with variable string

Tags: jquery

I'm a JQuery Newbie. I'm trying to append an object property( declared in an array form) to an html element like the following

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
<p>some text </p>
<p>some text </p>
<p>some text </p>
</div>
```

JQuery Script:

```
var obj{
property  :  {'apple', 'orange', 'banana'}
}

for(i=0; i<=2; i++){
$("#container p:eq("+i+")").append(obj.property[i]);
}
```

and hope to get this:

```
<p>some text apple</p>
<p>some text orange</p>
<p>some text banana</p>
```

There are no appending shown at all, though my Firebug console shows no error report.

What am I doing wrong? Also, is there any way to replace the for loop with .each(), if it's a better practice?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your list of properties isn't correctly formed. A numerically indexed list literal is formed using square brackets, not curly brackets.

The code you posted *should* be giving you a syntax error. If it's not, it's possible that it's simply not getting executed at all.

Here's a fixed up version:

```
  var obj = {
    property  :  ['apple', 'orange', 'banana'] 
  }

  for(i=0; i<=2; i++){
    $("#container p:eq("+i+")").append(obj.property[i]);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated in another answer, `obj` should be defined as such:

```
var obj = {
  property : ['apple', 'orange', 'banana']
}
```

The for loop will work, but it seems better practice to use `.each()`, if for no other reason just because you don't have to hard-code the values -- if you use `for`, then if you ever change the number of properties, you'll have to go update that loop too. Here is how I would do it:

```
$("#container > p").each(function(i) { $(this).append(obj.property[i]); });
```